# How to record device screen video using iOS sdk?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I am doing a tutorial Application in which I have to take the `iOS screen video`.For view it is working fine but our requirement is to record the screen video when a video is running.I tried to play video using `UIWebview` and `MPMoviePlayer`.Until the player starts it is recording.But after starting the player I get only black screen.Any Suggestions.

I followed this link:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1703/_index.html

```
 -(void) startRecording {


    // create the AVAssetWriter

    NSString *moviePath = [[self pathToDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:OUTPUT_FILE_NAME];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:moviePath]) {

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:moviePath error:nil];

    }


    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];

    NSError *movieError = nil;

    [assetWriter release];

    assetWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:movieURL

                                                fileType: AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie

                                                   error: &movieError];

    NSDictionary *assetWriterInputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

      AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,

      [NSNumber numberWithInt:FRAME_WIDTH], AVVideoWidthKey,

      [NSNumber numberWithInt:FRAME_HEIGHT], AVVideoHeightKey,

      nil];

    assetWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo

      outputSettings:assetWriterInputSettings];

    assetWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;

    [assetWriter addInput:assetWriterInput];


    [assetWriterPixelBufferAdaptor release];

    assetWriterPixelBufferAdaptor = [[AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor  alloc]

    initWithAssetWriterInput:assetWriterInput

    sourcePixelBufferAttributes:nil];

    [assetWriter startWriting];


    firstFrameWallClockTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();

    [assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime: CMTimeMake(0, TIME_SCALE)];


    // start writing samples to it

    [assetWriterTimer release];

    assetWriterTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1

    target:self

      selector:@selector (writeSample:)

      userInfo:nil

      repeats:YES] ;


    }



    -(void) stopRecording {

    [assetWriterTimer invalidate];

    assetWriterTimer = nil;


    [assetWriter finishWriting];

    NSLog (@"finished writing");

    }

- (UIImage*)screenshot

{

    // Create a graphics context with the target size

    // On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration

    // On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext

    CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

CGFloat imageScale = imageSize.width / FRAME_WIDTH;

    if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, imageScale);

    else

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);


    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    // Iterate over every window from back to front

    for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows])

    {

        if (![window respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] || [window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])

        {

            // -renderInContext: renders in the coordinate space of the layer,

            // so we must first apply the layer's geometry to the graphics context

            CGContextSaveGState(context);

            // Center the context around the window's anchor point

            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [window center].x, [window center].y);

            // Apply the window's transform about the anchor point

            CGContextConcatCTM(context, [window transform]);

            // Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point

            CGContextTranslateCTM(context,

                                  -[window bounds].size.width * [[window layer] anchorPoint].x,

                                  -[window bounds].size.height * [[window layer] anchorPoint].y);


            // Render the layer hierarchy to the current context

            [[window layer] renderInContext:context];


            // Restore the context

            CGContextRestoreGState(context);

        }

    }


    // Retrieve the screenshot image

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();


    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    return image;

}

-(void) writeSample: (NSTimer*) _timer {

if (assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData) {

// CMSampleBufferRef sample = nil;



CVReturn cvErr = kCVReturnSuccess;



// get screenshot image!

CGImageRef image = (CGImageRef) [[self screenshot] CGImage];

NSLog (@"made screenshot");


// prepare the pixel buffer

CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = NULL;

CFDataRef imageData= CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image));

NSLog (@"copied image data");

cvErr = CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault,

FRAME_WIDTH,

FRAME_HEIGHT,

kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA,

(void*)CFDataGetBytePtr(imageData),

CGImageGetBytesPerRow(image),

NULL,

NULL,

NULL,

&pixelBuffer);

NSLog (@"CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes returned %d", cvErr);



// calculate the time

CFAbsoluteTime thisFrameWallClockTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();

CFTimeInterval elapsedTime = thisFrameWallClockTime - firstFrameWallClockTime;

NSLog (@"elapsedTime: %f", elapsedTime);

CMTime presentationTime =  CMTimeMake (elapsedTime * TIME_SCALE, TIME_SCALE);


// write the sample

BOOL appended = [assetWriterPixelBufferAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer withPresentationTime:presentationTime];



if (appended) {

NSLog (@"appended sample at time %lf", CMTimeGetSeconds(presentationTime));

} else {

NSLog (@"failed to append");

[self stopRecording];

self.startStopButton.selected = NO;

}

}

}
```

**Where:**

```
NSTimer *clockTimer;
NSTimer *assetWriterTimer;
AVMutableComposition *mutableComposition;
AVAssetWriter *assetWriter;
AVAssetWriterInput *assetWriterInput;
AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *assetWriterPixelBufferAdaptor;
CFAbsoluteTime firstFrameWallClockTime;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a sample app from iOS Developer Library. [AVSimpleEditor.](https://github.com/darcyliu/SampleCode/tree/master/AVSimpleEditoriOS/AVSimpleEditoriOS.xcodeproj) Along with the video recording it can trim, rotate, crop and add music.

**Description:**

AVSimpleEditor is a simple AVFoundation based movie editing application which exercises the APIs of AVVideoComposition, AVAudioMix and demonstrates how they can be used for simple video editing tasks. It also demonstrates how they interact with playback (AVPlayerItem) and export (AVAssetExportSession). The application performs trim, rotate, crop, add music, add watermark and export.